# Calculate the value range of a math formula with given bounds

Tags: python

Good day!

I am using python v3.8 and I want to calculate the value range (minimum and maximum) of a given formula with (also given) bounds e.g.:

```
formula1: a * sqrt(b/c)

formula2: a^2 * b/1000 + 3 * (a+b)

formula3: (1/(2 * PI * (a * 1000) * (b * 1000)) * 10^12

..with a=[0,5], b=[10,20], c=[30,40]
```

I am not too familiar with scipy, numpy, sympy.. and I wonder if there is an "easy" way to just calculate the formula with different values, write it into an array and get the min/max from that? The problem I have with "writing into an array and get min/max" is, that there are some bounds [-100000, 100000] with given float numbers and that would generate way too much values.

I do not need the information with which values the minimum/maximum was reached, but only which min/max values can be reached.

Comment: Are there methods? Yes.

Comment: Create a matrix with 3 columns with the values of a, b, and c that you want to evaluate, and then create a fourth column with one of those formulas. COmputing the max and the min should be trivial.

Comment: @Adirio Yeah, now im using this kind of "solver". Numpy offers a function / for-loop for floating numbers and that is very helpful. Unfortunately all depends on the "step" the variable is iterating through. In one case I had a range given from 0.1 to 2 and I chose a step-range of 0.1 and I got the result of ~3600. With a 0.01 step the result was ~3900.. For a first rough estimation it is "okay-ish" I guess. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, the step will influence in your results as you are basically working with a continuous formula in a discrete world. Imagine the maximum value is for `a = 1.324567`. If you get a step of `0.1` your local max will be for `a = 1.3` probably but that's not the real maximum. If you decrease the step to `0.01`, your loxal maximum will be on `a = 1.32`, whose value will be different to `a = 1.3`. If you want to be exact you will have to compute the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Symbolic:

Maximum and minimum points are called critical points. To find a critical point you need to a partial derivative respect every variable (`f'_a = df/da`, `f'_b = df/db`, `f'_c = df/dc`), and solve the system of equations where all of them are equal to 0. We can do this with `sympy`.

```py
import sympy as sp

a = sp.Symbol('a', real=True)
b = sp.Symbol('b', real=True)
c = sp.Symbol('c', real=True)

functions = [
    a * sp.sqrt(b / c),
    a**2 * b/1000 + 3*(a+b),
    10**6 / (2 * sp.pi * a * b),
]

for f in functions:
    f_a, f_b, f_c = f.diff(a), f.diff(b), f.diff(c)
    print(f"f(a, b, c) = {f}")
    print(f"f'_a(a, b, c) = {f_a} = 0")
    print(f"f'_b(a, b, c) = {f_b} = 0")
    print(f"f'_c(a, b, c) = {f_c} = 0")
    print("Critical points:", sp.solve([f_a, f_b, f_c], a, b, c))
    print()
```

As you can see if you execute this code, there is no critical point, so no absolute maximum nor minimum value for any of these funtions in the Real domain (there are two critical points for the second equation in the Imaginary domain).

#### Numeric approach:

Using `numpy` and `pandas` we can create a matrix with all the possible combinations and then apply each of our functions. The maximum and minimum values are per column, they are not related between the columns. As expected, the max and min values for the a, b and c columns are the range lower and upper bounds.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.reshape.util import cartesian_product
import numpy as np


# Number of values per range
N = 21

# Functions
functions = [
    lambda row: row['a'] * np.sqrt(row['b'] / row['c']),
    lambda row: row['a']**2 * row['b']/1000 + 3*(row['a']+row['b']),
    lambda row: 10**6 / (2 * np.pi * row['a'] * row['b']),
]

# Lower and upper bounds
a_lower, a_upper = 0, 5
b_lower, b_upper = 10, 20
c_lower, c_upper = 30, 40


def min_max(col):
    return pd.Series(index=['min', 'max'], data=[col.min(), col.max()])


values = [
    np.linspace(a_lower, a_upper, N),
    np.linspace(b_lower, b_upper, N),
    np.linspace(c_lower, c_upper, N),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(cartesian_product(values), index=['a', 'b', 'c']).T
for i, f in enumerate(functions):
    df[f'f_{i + 1}'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df.apply(min_max))
```

Output:

```
       a     b     c       f_1   f_2          f_3
min  0.0  10.0  30.0  0.000000  30.0  1591.549431
max  5.0  20.0  40.0  4.082483  75.5          inf
```

`N = 101` has exactly the same output (it takes a bit to process as it has to compute the formulas 101^3 > 1M times)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much Adirio. 
This works much better than my previous attempt. Also this gives me the oppurtunity to read String-formula and convert them to numpy-formula to calculate not just "pre-constructed in python"-formulas. And it is easily possible to add more variables and spans to it too. Nice! 
I am using the eval() function for that (I know about the safety-issues with eval()). 


I searched about the eval() usage and found the comment "numpy.eval() should be better than the pure eval() function" but I could not see the advantages of the numpy.eval()

Answer (score 1):

Try [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html) solvers, they have solveset that can do the following:

```
>>> solveset(Eq(x**2, 1), x)
{-1, 1}
```

Comment: `sympy.solveset` solves equations, but he didn't post any equation.